# Leakage after using the back window windscreen washer

Tags: audi, windshield-washer

I have a Audi A3 Quattro where each time I use the windscreen washer just for the back window the back passenger seats become wet.  There must be a leakage.

I know I have to get this problem fixed - bit worried about the cost.

Hoping to sell it next year - I know I have to get this problem fixed before hand.

Any advice anyone

Comment: I'm not familiar with the A3, but if you could remove some panel in the back or from the ceiling you will have a better look on where the leakage occurs. I've seen a washer fluid disconnect one in a car and every time the pump was activated the fluid was projected inside the body panel.

Answer (score 1):

The interior panels on the tailgate of your A3 simply pull off to expose the hose for the rear wash. You need to check the washer jet in the rear wiper arm is not blocked, and the hoses are intact as well. A blocked washer jet can dislodge the hose.

Comment: Hi, Thank you Allan.  I will try and have a look :)